# git pull remote master in detached head

Tags: git, git-patch, git-detached-head

This has been bothering me about git.  I have a repository with multiple remotes, and I need to apply hotfixes to the remotes' master branches.  So, I try doing:

```
git fetch remote1 master
git checkout remote1/master
```

But, I always end up in a detached head state.  What is the correct way to checkout the master of a remote and apply a patch?

Comment: No, `git fetch` will not move your HEAD, and will therefore not result in detatched head. And your `git pull` command is invalid: it needs a remote as argument, not some remote branch. please add what *exactly* you did, and why you believe it results in detached head.

Comment: Ok, I think I clarified this a little better.  And fixed the commands to what I was actually doing and not what I thought I was doing.  Sorry about that.

Comment: @user2659205 Thanks for updating your commands.  I've updated my answer, but a quick question: is `remote1` actually `origin` in your case?  Or is it really a different repository?  Do you have permission to push to it?  Are you looking to share the patch you're making?  All of these questions affect the answer. :-(  I made a couple of assumptions in my answer, but I can change it if your situation is different.

Comment: Yeah, remote1 is a separate repo, and I have access.  I was trying to figure out the best workflow for doing hotfixes to our test and live servers.
Thanks for your detailed answer.  That's pretty much what I ended up doing.  And yes, I'm still new to git, so I'm still learning, and I'll definitely check out those sites.
I guess I just have a problem with the idea that I need to checkout remote1 into a different branch.  It just feels weird, but I'll get used to it :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

None of those commands will give you a detached head.  Is there something else that you're doing that you haven't written down in your question?

```
git fetch remote1
```

This will fetch anything matching the default refspec for `remote1`.  That typically means all branches on `remote1` unless you've configured it differently.

```
git fetch remote1 master
```

The above command fetches `master` from `remote1` and stores it as `FETCH_HEAD`.

```
git pull remote1/master
```

This command will error out because `remote1/master` is not the name of a repository.

There are a few ways you could approach the problem, but it really depends on what you're trying to accomplish.  The typical approach would be to create a local branch for the remote branch you want to update, and merge the corresponding branch:

```
git checkout -b r1-master remote1/master
git merge other/master
git push
```

But, it's unclear whether that's an acceptable workflow for you.  Can you post more information about what you're trying to accomplish?

### Update

Thanks for updating your question with the actual commands used.

```
git fetch remote1 master
```

The above command grabs the latest content of master and stores it in `FETCH_HEAD`.  You want to leave off the `master` here and let Git update your remote references: `git fetch remote1`.  At this pointer, `remote1/master` should be up-to-date with what's on the server.

```
git checkout remote1/master
```

This is the command that gives you a detached `HEAD`.  Remote refs aren't treated the same as local branches (refs in `refs/heads`).  When you checkout a remote ref, Git puts you in a detached HEAD state.  I believe the idea behind this is to keep you from corrupting your view of the remote branches.  The remote refs are there to serve as a snapshot of the state of the remote repository the last time you fetched.  Letting you commit to them would ruin that view.  Local branches are where edits need to be made.

Let's make a couple of assumptions.  First, I'm going to assume that `remote1` is not `origin` and that you have added this remote to interact with a different repository other than the primary one.  Secondly, I'm assuming that you have the ability to push code to `remote1`.

Before going an further, let's **make sure that `push.default` is set to a reasonable value**.  Run `git config --global push.default`.  If nothing is returned, or it says `matching`, then let's change it.  The default configuration (`matching`) will attempt to update all refs on a push for a particular remote.  This has the side effect of removing people's work if you don't keep the local versions of your branches up-to-date.  A better default is `upstream`, which will only push the branch that you are on.  Set it with:

```
git config --global push.default upstream
```

The typical way to add a patch in Git is to create a branch, make your patch, merge it into the local representation of the remote branch, and then push the result to the remote branch.

Let's start by creating a local branch of the remote master:

```
git checkout -b r1-master remote1/master
```

Now we have a local branch called `r1-master` that we can update (`HEAD` will *not* be detached on this branch).

Next, do your work.  This typically involves creating another branch and adding your series of patches to it:

```
git checkout -b fix-bugs r1-master
# Edit and commit
```

Next, you'll need to checkout `r1-master` again.  While making your changes, someone could have introduced new commits on `remote1/master`, so let's make sure we're up-to-date:

```
git fetch remote1
```

Next, merge in the bug fix branch:

```
git merge fix-bugs
```

This will pop open an editor.  Add a sensible log message about what the merge fixes, and then save and exit.

At this point, `r1-master` has your fix in it, but it's not on the remote server.  We need to push our newly introduced fix to the remote server:

```
git push
```

At this point, `r1-master` and `remote1/master` should point to the same thing, and the remote server has been updated with your fix.

### Other help

For what it's worth, it looks like you're new to Git, so let me point you at a couple of tutorials.  The first is [Try Git](http://try.github.io/).  I like it because you can try the commands right there on the web page, but it's not very in-depth.  [Git Immersion](http://gitimmersion.com/) goes more in depth, and has an excellent presentation of the concepts behind Git.  NDP Software's [Git Cheatsheet](http://ndpsoftware.com/git-cheatsheet.html) is also an excellent reference on how commands affect the local and remote repository.  Finally, [Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book) is a good book to get you started.  The online version is free.

Answer (score 2):

`git fetch remote1 master` will fetch the master branch of remote and store it in `FETCH_HEAD`, **not** in `remote1/master`. - You simply want `git fetch remote1`, or `git fetch --all`.

`git checkout remote1/master` will always put you in detached head mode, because you did not specify a local branch. - You want something like `git checkout -b master remote1/master`.

Please read `git help fetch` and `git help checkout`.